# MongoDB performance query with indexes

Tags: php, mongodb, indexing, bdd

I can't find any information in the MongoDB documentation. I would like to know if performing a search with an indexed field + an unindexed field will "help" MongoDB to search faster by limiting the results or on the contrary slow it down by having to analyze all the documents?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In general, indexing the fields used in query filter and sort operations helps perform better. Indexes can be on single or multiple fields. Yes, you can have a query filter with an indexed field + non-indexed field - but, your chances of performance is better if there is a compound index on both the fields.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. MongoDb will still use the index if there is an unindexed field in the request? I want to use only one index. The results of the query allow me 2 choices. Either use only the indexed field in the request and put a condition in the results or directly use the indexed field + the non-indexed field directly in the request. I don't know which is better in terms of performance?

Comment: _"MongoDb will still use the index if there is an unindexed field in the request? ""_: Yes, it will use the index if the query filter has at least one indexed field. You can verify the index usage by generation a _query plan_ (using the `explain()` with `executionStats` mode). Query plans will help analyze the query performance.

Comment: Thanks for your help.